# Como utilizar private e public numa classe simples no C++?

Tags: c++, classes, private, void, public

Estou tentando colocar o "string nome;" no private e acessar ele do public, mas estou com muita dificuldade em fazer isso no C++. Todas as vezes que tentei deu falha para executar o código. Gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar. Segue o código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Aluno
{
public:
//O string nome deixei aqui porque dessa forma o
// compilador está executando sem erros.
//Mas, como adicionar ele no privado e 
//chamar ele no publico e no int main ()?
   
    string nome;
    void setIda(int age)
    {
        if (age > 0 && age < 60)
            idade = age;
        else
            idade = 0;
    }
    int getIda()
    {
        return idade;
    }
    void setMatr(int matr)
    {
        if (matr > 0 && matr <= 1000)
            matricula = matr;
        else
            matricula = 0;
    }
    int getMatr()
    {
        return matricula;
    }
//Eu gostaria de chamar o string nome; no privado e depois
// chamar ele no publico.
// Nao sei como proceder com ele aqui.

     private:
       int matricula;
       int idade;
    };
// Depois de fazer a chamada do string nome no privado e chamar no publico, 
//como devo chamar ele no int main()?

    int main()
    {
        Aluno *novo_aluno1 = new Aluno();
        Aluno *novo_aluno2 = new Aluno();

        novo_aluno1->nome = "John Smith";
        novo_aluno1->setIda(32);
        novo_aluno1->setMatr(999);

        novo_aluno2->nome = "Mary Smith";
        novo_aluno2->setIda(21);
        novo_aluno2->setMatr(998);

        cout << "\nNome: " << novo_aluno1->nome << "\n";
        cout << "Idade: " << novo_aluno1->getIda() << "\n";
        cout << "Matricula: " << novo_aluno1->getMatr() << "\n";

        cout << "\nNome: " << novo_aluno2->nome << "\n";
        cout << "Idade: " << novo_aluno2->getIda() << "\n";
        cout << "Matricula: " << novo_aluno2->getMatr() << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Que significa _como adicionar ele no privado e chamar ele no publico_ ? Não é um contra senso? private é justamente isso. Se não precisa disso use acesso público e pronto. Para que o `new`? Não precisa disso. E se usa isso deveria ter um correspondente `delete`

Comment: porque não usa um GetNome() também? Resolveria seu problema de público/privado

Comment: @arfneto, desculpa, reconheço que não formulei corretamente a pergunta. Na verdade estou apresentando a fonte executável, mas não consegui adicionar no privado 'private' para que ele não fosse alterado. Ao mesmo tempo existe a possibilidade de usar ele sem alterar a fonte original. Mas, não estava conseguindo fazer isso usando a forma correta.

Comment: @arfneto, eu consegui agora fazendo justamente isso que me disse.             public: 
    void setName(string name){
        nome = name;
    }
    string getName(){
        return nome;
    }

Comment: `private` não faz com que ele não possa ser alterado. Apenas deixa o valor inacessível fora da classe

Comment: Sim. Eu entendo o que você está dizendo. Como sou iniciante tenho dificuldade ao expressar sobre a fonte. Eu gostaria de deixar string nome no privado e depois alterá-lo, como fiz com outros membros.

Answer (score 1):

Considere esse exemplo, que tem alguns dos modos comuns de fazer isso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Aluno
{
   private:
    string nome;
    int    idade;
    int    matricula;

   public:
    void setIda(int age)
    {
        idade = (age > 0 && age < 60) ? age : 0;
    }
    int getIda() { return idade; }

    void setMatr(int matr)
    {
        if (matr > 0 && matr <= 1000)
            matricula = matr;
        else
            matricula = 0;
    }
    int getMatr() { return matricula; }

    void   setNome(string nome) { Aluno::nome = nome; }
    string getNome() { return nome; }

    Aluno(string nome, int idade, int mat)
        : nome(nome), idade(idade), matricula(mat){};

    Aluno() : Aluno("", 0, 0){};  // padrao

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Aluno&);
};

int main(void)
{
    Aluno aluno1("John Smith", 32, 999);
    Aluno aluno2("Mary Smith", 21, 998);

    cout << aluno1;
    cout << aluno2;

    Aluno* aluno = new Aluno("Emmylou Harris", 65, 99890);
    cout << *aluno;

    Aluno turma[20];   // 20 alunos;
    cout << "Decimo Aluno: " << turma[9];  // o decimo
    turma[9].setNome("Decimo");
    turma[9].setIda(42);
    cout << "Mudado o nome para \"Decimo\" e idade para "
            "42\n";
    cout << "Decimo Aluno: " << turma[9];  // o decimo


    Aluno* dois = new Aluno[2];  // 2 ponteiros para aluno
    // nao apontam para nada ainda
    dois[1] = aluno2;
    dois[0] = *aluno;
    // agora apontam
    cout << "Do vetor de ponteiros:\n";
    cout << dois[0];
    cout << dois[1];

    delete aluno;   // apaga tudo que
    delete[] dois;  // alocou  

    // modo recomendado
    unique_ptr<Aluno> al = std::make_unique<Aluno>("Ponteiro esperto", 11, 334455);
    cout << *al;

    return 0;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& saida, Aluno& A)
{
    saida << "Nome: " << A.nome << " (" << A.idade << "a.)"
          << " Mat: " << A.matricula << "\n";
    return saida;
}
```

#### saída

```
Nome: John Smith (32a.) Mat: 999
Nome: Mary Smith (21a.) Mat: 998
Nome: Emmylou Harris (65a.) Mat: 99890
Decimo Aluno: Nome:  (0a.) Mat: 0
Mudado o nome para "Decimo" e idade para 42
Decimo Aluno: Nome: Decimo (42a.) Mat: 0
Do vetor de ponteiros:
Nome: Emmylou Harris (65a.) Mat: 99890
Nome: Mary Smith (21a.) Mat: 998
Nome: Ponteiro esperto (11a.) Mat: 334455
```

- note a presença de um construtor e o uso dele: é a maneira simples de iniciar a classe
- um construtor padrão é o que não tem parâmetros e pode ver o uso: nesse caso, só para ilustrar, o registro é criado com nome em branco idade 0 e matrícula 0. Vai ser usado no caso do vetor `turma` onde tem que criar os 20 `Aluno`
- `aluno1` e `aluno2` existem durante todo o programa então não há razão para usar ponteiros e alocação dinãmica nesse caso. Foi o que eu disse no comentário.
- mas, se precisa usar, uma maneira de usar está no exemplo para um vetor de 2 ponteiros e para um ponteiro.
- Note que o uso de ponteiros em C++ é desencorajado há décadas. O recomendado é usar `unique_ptr` que é automaticamente apagado quando não mais em uso.
- redefinindo o operador `<<` e declarando como `friend` dá a ele acesso às variáveis da instância da classe e vai ver que é bem conveniente.

Comment: Muito obrigado, @arfneto! A fonte está ainda melhor para ser estudado. Você adicionou pontos que eu preciso ainda entender melhor. De qualquer forma, isso aumentou a minha ideia sobre o que pode ser ainda feito. Valeu!